# (Excel) Nested IF or AND Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formulas, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that averages a set of various data. I need a way to display nothing if cell N2 contains the value 9999.09, to make sure that value is not included in the averaging.

**Excel code that needs to be modified:**

```
=IF(T2+0<5,N6,N4)
```

**I tried**

```
=IF(AND(T2+0<5,N2=9999.09,N6,N4))
```

but that doesn't work because it really is a two condition statement. Also cell T2 displays the current hour.

Comment: Not really clear on the problem you are describing. But can you not just use `IF(N2<>9999.09,N2,"")` ? The fact that you are giving such a specific target figure (9999.09) makes me think I've misunderstood. I also don't understand where the values have come from in `T2+0<5`

Comment: Hi roganjosh,     "T2+0>5" refers to the current hour and 5 is a specific hour in time, e.x. 5:00am.

Comment: Just FYI, you never closed the "AND" for the `=if(and(...`.  Did you perhaps mean `=IF(AND(T2+0<5,N2=9999.09),N6,N4)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(N2=9999.09,"", Do what you wish)
```

you can pass through "" as a null text string.

Comment: This appears to accomplish what I want. =IF(N2=9999.09,"",IF(T2+0<5,N4,N2))

Comment: better version would be to use an array formula:

  =AVERAGE(IF(RANGE=TESTVALUE,RANGE))

and close of with Control+Shift+Enter

Comment: @user2697139 I'm not sure how that's a "better" answer as it has none of the additional functionality eluded to in the question or in the OP's comment.